# MVC ASP.NET Creating two models that are associated in a single view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET and I have two models, Contact and Customer and there is a one to one relationship between the two. So, every contact will be added in the contacts entity and when a contact is a customer, the extra information will be added in the customer entity.

I created a ViewModel containing both. When the view model is then passed in the post request, i add first the contact, which adds correctly and then I want to add the customer with relationship to the previous contact, but I don't know how to do it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerCreate(CustomerViewModel customerViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new ModelContactContainer())
            {
                db.Contact.Add(customerViewModel.contact);
                customerViewModel.customer.Contact = customerViewModel.contact;
                db.Customer.Add(customerViewModel.customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return CustomerCreate();
        }
    }
    return CustomerCreate();
}
```

**UPDATE**

These are the classes for my models:

*Contact.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public partial class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

*Customer.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

*CustomerViewModel.cs*

```
public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public Contact contact { get; set; }
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the view

*CustomerCreate.cshtml*

```
@model W3SchoolsApplication.Models.CustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Customer";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contact.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contact.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contact.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.customer.Something, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer.Something, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer.Something, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have? Is it not working or do you get an error?

Comment: @PuR3v1L How do the tables in your database look? Which one contains the foreign key towards the other?

Comment: @RaduPorumb Actually, the way Entity Framework created them, there is a reference in both of them for the other one, since the relationship is one to one.

Comment: @RaduPorumb Sorry, now I saw that you said in the database. In the database there is a foreign key in the customer table pointing to the contacts table, and that is how I need it because I will add more models (employees, suppliers, etc) and a person could be 2 or 3 things simultaneously

Comment: Try turning off lazy loading - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: @VisualBean I tried it and it didn't make a difference

Comment: I'd say that  db.savechanges() and then adding the contact to the viewmodel.Customer.Contact - should work as prescribed by Radu. hmm

Comment: @RaduPorumb Ok, i made it work. The problem was the ModelState.IsValid, which, for some reason, is never true. So I just removed it and left the `try{} catch{}` block and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand what happens behind the scenes to understand why this doesn't work.

```
using (var db = new ModelContactContainer())
{
    db.Contact.Add(customerViewModel.contact);
    db.SaveChanges(); // so the above has an ID and the foreign key relationship works

    // this doesn't add anything to the database, it just populates the foreign key relationship
    customerViewModel.customer.Contact = customerViewModel.contact; 
    db.Customer.Add(customerViewModel.customer);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you want this entire operation to be atomic you'll have to wrap it in a transaction, like so:

```
using (var db = new ModelContactContainer())
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    db.Contact.Add(customerViewModel.contact);
    db.SaveChanges();

    customerViewModel.customer.Contact = customerViewModel.contact; 
    db.Customer.Add(customerViewModel.customer);
    db.SaveChanges();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, it won't add to the database. Please see my updated post and thank you very much for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you should change the order and you probably don't have to add contact explicit:

```
        customerViewModel.customer.Contact = customerViewModel.contact;
        db.Contact.Add(customerViewModel.customer);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I found the answer, look at my comments, thanks anyway, but I have to add the contact explicitly, in order to populate the foreign key attribute correctly. :)